# Web site generation automitacally when new tab appears

Tags: web

I am facing a problem with my google crome.

When I try to open a new tab then awebsite generates itself called

"http://www.trovigo.com/"..

So how do I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a kind of viruses, toolbar virus 
you could fix it easy

instructions here : [How to remove Trovigo.com Toolbar & Other Viruses](http://www.techsupportall.com/remove-trovigo-com-virus-ie-chrome-firefox/)